# Remove dotted border around focused option in select

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

How can I remove the dotted border around the focused item in the select box that appears in Firefox (78.0.1). I have tried all suggested solutions but none seem to work.

[image]

Here's the css that i have tried:

```
:focus {
    outline:none;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
    outline: none; 
}

select {
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}

select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/rs10v72d/

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the browser you are using. Some browers have these types of built-in things. Like in the latest version of Google Chrome, when you click on such type of thing, the border becomes fully black.